# Accessing C++ one dimensional array like arr[1,2,3] - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

consider this code (it compiles and runs on VisualStudio 2012)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int arr[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        arr[i]=i;

    int a = arr[10]; // 10
    int a1 = arr[10,10]; // 10 <-
    int a3 = arr[5,10,7]; // 7 <-
    int a4 = arr[5,10,7,2]; // 2 <-
}
```

I don't understand what is the meaning of the lines marked with <-
I expected a compilation error.
The actual result is like specifying only the last number in the []

So,
What does it mean? What is it good for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not some special array subscripting syntax. The expression inside the square brackets is being evaluated to a single value and then that value is used to index the array. So the last of your lines is equivalent to:

```
int a4 = arr[(5,10,7,2)];
```

So how is that expression being evaluated? It uses the comma operator. The comma operator evaluates its left operand and discards it, then evaluates its right operand. The value of the expression is the value of the right operand. When you have a bunch of them next to each other like that, the value is the rightmost value - in the above case, 2. So now it is equivalent to:

```
int a4 = arr[2];
```

The comma operator has fairly limited use, but [some of its uses are outlined on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Uses). In general, it is useful for evaluating two distinct expressions when an enclosing block is not available (such as in a static initialiser). However, in this case, using it has no effect.

Comment: Do you have an example where the comma operator is useful ?

Comment: @Daniel in `for` loops, you can use `i++, j++`.

Answer (score 2):

That's the **comma operator** - all expressions are evaluated, and the last one is used. There's no reason for it here, it only hinders readability. The code is identical to

```
int a = arr[10]; // 10
int a1 = arr[10]; // 10 <-
int a3 = arr[7]; // 7 <-
int a4 = arr[2]; // 2 <-
```